# How to represent scalar variables over geographic map in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gis

I am representing some geographical data in a Jupyter notebook: temperature, ocean wave height, etc. I have numpy arrays that have the latitude, longitude, and value for those variables. I would like to display these variables over a geographical map, preferably using ipyleaflet (because that is what I am already using). I am trying to get a result similar to a heatmap.

I tried to use the ipyleaflet Heatmap, but it seems to me that it is designed to represent agregation of points and not scalar uniform arrays, because I can't get it to show the results properly. I think ipyleaflet may lack a function to represent this kind of data, but seems odd since it has a very nice Velocity funtion to represent vectorial variables.

The only way I can think of to make this would be to generate an image with matplotlib and then adding it to the map in an  image layer, but I feel like that is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: Matplotlib would be a great way to accomplish this, per this example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_species_kde.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-species-kde-py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For representing a heatmap I would recommend to use Cartopy in combination with Matplotlib.
Here a ready to use script I made for a world projection with a coastline:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point


# Set x y z variables
x = longitude_data
y = latitude_data
z = heat_map_data

# Set up figure and projection
z, x = add_cyclic_point(z, coord=x) 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree() )

# Set data range and colourmap
levels = np.arange(min,max,steps) 
plt.contourf(x, y, z,levels = levels,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap="rainbow")

# Set axes, extent (world) and labels 
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(-180,180,num=7), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-60,60,num=5), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE) #Add coastline
ax.set_global()
ax.set_title('Heatmap')
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')

# Add colorbar 
plt.colorbar(ax=ax,shrink=0.7,orientation="vertical")

fig.show()
```

With the Cartopy and Matplotlib documentation you should now be able to create some maps.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you can generate an image and overlay it onto the map. This is the suggestion I was given [when I asked about this on Github](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/503).

There's an example notebook [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/blob/master/examples/Numpy.ipynb).
Not quite as easy as matplotlib, but you get all the nice interactivity of ipyleaflet!

Here's the current version of the notebook in case the link changes (converted to markdown via `jupyter-nbconvert --to markdown Numpy.ipynb`)

---

## From NumPy to Leaflet

This notebook shows how to display some raster geographic data in IPyLeaflet. The data is a NumPy array, which means that you have all the power of the Python scientific stack at your disposal to process it.

The following libraries are needed:
* `requests`
* `tqdm`
* `rasterio`
* `numpy`
* `scipy`
* `pillow`
* `matplotlib`
* `ipyleaflet`

The recommended way is to try to `conda install` them first, and if they are not found then `pip install`.

```py
import requests
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import zipfile
import rasterio
from affine import Affine
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from base64 import b64encode
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO, BytesIO
    py3 = True
from ipyleaflet import Map, ImageOverlay, basemap_to_tiles, basemaps
```

Download a raster file representing the flow accumulation for South America. This gives an idea of the river network.

```py
url = 'https://edcintl.cr.usgs.gov/downloads/sciweb1/shared/hydrosheds/sa_30s_zip_grid/sa_acc_30s_grid.zip'
filename = os.path.basename(url)
name = filename[:filename.find('_grid')]
adffile = name + '/' + name + '/w001001.adf'

if not os.path.exists(adffile):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
        for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), total=(total_length/1024) + 1):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
    zip.extractall('.')
```

We transform the data a bit so that rivers appear thicker.

```py
dataset = rasterio.open(adffile)
acc_orig = dataset.read()[0]
acc = np.where(acc_orig<0, 0, acc_orig)

shrink = 1 # if you are out of RAM try increasing this number (should be a power of 2)
radius = 5 # you can play with this number to change the width of the rivers
circle = np.zeros((2*radius+1, 2*radius+1)).astype('uint8')
y, x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1,-radius:radius+1]
index = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2
circle[index] = 1
acc = np.sqrt(acc)
acc = scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter(acc, footprint=circle)
acc[acc_orig<0] = np.nan
acc = acc[::shrink, ::shrink]
```

The original data is in the WGS 84 projection, but Leaflet uses Web Mercator, so we need to reproject.

```py
# At this point if GDAL complains about not being able to open EPSG support file gcs.csv, try in the terminal:
# export GDAL_DATA=`gdal-config --datadir`

with rasterio.Env():
    rows, cols = acc.shape
    src_transform = list(dataset.transform)
    src_transform[0] *= shrink
    src_transform[4] *= shrink
    src_transform = Affine(*src_transform[:6])
    src_crs = {'init': 'EPSG:4326'}
    source = acc

    dst_crs = {'init': 'EPSG:3857'}
    dst_transform, width, height = rasterio.warp.calculate_default_transform(src_crs, dst_crs, cols, rows, *dataset.bounds)
    dst_shape = height, width

    destination = np.zeros(dst_shape)

    reproject(
        source,
        destination,
        src_transform=src_transform,
        src_crs=src_crs,
        dst_transform=dst_transform,
        dst_crs=dst_crs,
        resampling=Resampling.nearest)

acc_web = destination
```

Let's convert our NumPy array to an image. For that we must specify a colormap (here `plt.cm.jet`).

```py
acc_norm = acc_web - np.nanmin(acc_web)
acc_norm = acc_norm / np.nanmax(acc_norm)
acc_norm = np.where(np.isfinite(acc_web), acc_norm, 0)
acc_im = PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(plt.cm.jet(acc_norm)*255))
acc_mask = np.where(np.isfinite(acc_web), 255, 0)
mask = PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(acc_mask), mode='L')
im = PIL.Image.new('RGBA', acc_norm.shape[::-1], color=None)
im.paste(acc_im, mask=mask)
```

The image is embedded in the URL as a PNG file, so that it can be sent to the browser.

```py
if py3:
    f = BytesIO()
else:
    f = StringIO()
im.save(f, 'png')
data = b64encode(f.getvalue())
if py3:
    data = data.decode('ascii')
imgurl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data

Not quite as easy as matplotlib, but you get all the nice interactivity of ipyleaflet!
```

Finally we can overlay our image and if everything went fine it should be exactly over South America.

```py
b = dataset.bounds
bounds = [(b.bottom, b.left), (b.top, b.right)]
io = ImageOverlay(url=imgurl, bounds=bounds)
```

```py
center = [-10, -60]
zoom = 2
m = Map(center=center, zoom=zoom, interpolation='nearest')
m
```

```py
tile = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.Esri.WorldStreetMap)
m.add_layer(tile)
```

You can play with the opacity slider and check that rivers from our data file match the rivers on OpenStreetMap.

```py
m.add_layer(io)
io.interact(opacity=(0.0,1.0,0.01))
```

---